# How to solve: inline checked attributes will be ignored when using v-model

Tags: checkbox, vuejs2, vue-component

I'm creating a component en VueJS and when I created the following checkbox:

```
<div class="checkbox-inline">
    <label><input type="checkbox" checked="checked" v-model="sendEnter">Send with Enter</label>
  </div><!-- /.checkbox -->
```

I kept getting error:
`inline checked attributes will be ignored when using v-model. Declare initial values in the component's data option instead.`

But I already had

```
  data(){
   return{
     textMsg: '',
     sendEnter: 'checked'
   }
  }
```

In the component. Why I keep getting this error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to remove `checked="checked"` from the input label.